# AesCryptoServiceProvider in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.ios, cryptography, aes

I'm working in the iPad version of my app and I have a function in what I use `AesCryptoServiceProvider` for example the following lines

```
 using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
 {
    setAesProviderSettings(aesProvider);
    result = aesProvider.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
 }
```

It works in my Android app(MonDroid) and in a .NET(WPF) application but in iOS I got  this error;

```
Error  5      The type or namespace name 'AesCryptoServiceProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The function is in my core project and I use the project linker to reference it in the iPad project and also I use project linker in the Android version, of course in the three platforms is the same file with all the references that it need. I use Xamarin with Visual Studio 12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the factory method `Aes.Create ()` and your code will be more portable across different .NET versions/platforms. E.g.

```
using (var aesProvider = Aes.Create ()) {
   setAesProviderSettings(aesProvider);
   result = aesProvider.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
}
```

In Xamarin.iOS it will return `AesManaged` (from `System.Core.dll`) but, in reality, it's calling Apple CommonCrypto (it's not a managed implementation) which can be hardware accelerated (depending on your devices).